# How to pass javascript variable value to the php variable on the same page using ajax without reloading?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I try to pass a javascript variable value to php variable using ajax.
I want to pass the value without reloading the page.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var str = "tes";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                value: str
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    </script>

    <?php
       $result = $_POST['value'];
       echo $result;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I get "Undefined array key 'value'" error
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: PHP is server-side, meaning it’s rendered by the server and given to the client. It can’t dynamically change or rerender without a refresh. You want to use JavaScript.

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias i still don't get the value even if i put the url to reload

Comment: That’s because you’re using AJAX and not just a normal form post request. AJAX doesn’t reload the page. You need to submit the data using a standard http request. AJAX is xhr, not http

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias to be pedantic, XHR still sends a http request, it's just one that the browser sends in the background asynchronously rather than reloading the whole page. That's the only difference. The protocol used is identical, and the server can't tell the difference between an xhr request and any other - it looks like just another http request

Comment: @ADyson of course, though it’s pretty common to differentiate them by XHR and HTTP.

Comment: @VeriVirgandra you've misunderstood the concept here a bit. You can send data to the server using ajax, and make it run a php script, but the data you get back doesn't automatically update your page- you have to write JS code inside your "success" function to do any updates that you require. And if you write php code in your page, that runs when you first loaded the page, not just when you run the ajax request. So the error you've got is because the POST value doesn't exist when you originally load the page and execute that php

Comment: ...and it's normally more logical and maintainable to have the ajax request trigger a _different_ php script, one which purely does the processing needed for the ajax request to get the input sent and respond with suitable output, rather than requesting the main page all over again

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias `it’s pretty common to differentiate them by XHR and HTTP`...nope, i have to say I've never come across that one - probably because they aren't mutually exclusive things. Xhr is just a mechanism for sending a http request, not an alternative to http. I've never seen anyone make that distinction as you've described it. It's simply an xhr request, or not an xhr request (or maybe a "standard" request some might call it)

Comment: @ADyson right, a standard http request… let’s not conflate our experiences in different countries, in different stacks as if they’re facts.

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias "standard http request" is fine, but to say "you need xhr not http", putting "http" vs "xhr" - and making it sound like xhr is not a http request, is not a good description. Let's leave it there.

Comment: @ADyson should’ve left it at “pedantic”, to be honest.

Comment: @ShaunE.Tobias Words and terminology matter greatly in programming. Incorrect use of terminology (even just casually rather than through genuine ignorance) frequently leads to ambiguity, miscommunication, confusion, mistakes, wasted time, wasted money, even security breaches etc etc. I've seen it too many times. Maybe in this case it wouldn't have done any harm, but if the OP gets a misunderstanding about what xhr is, it might lead to wasted effort or confusion later on. So I'm not going to apologise for being pedantic about use of language. It's nothing personal.

Answer (score 1):

dear user you are doing in a wrong way please specify the request method because right now the php code executed directly when page load use the below code

```
<?php
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=='POST'){
    $result = $_POST['value'];
    echo $result;
  }else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var str = "tes";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            value: str
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```